# How to connect to a database inside a BeanFactoryPostProcessor?

Tags: java, database, spring, runtime-configuration

I am working on a project using Spring Data JPA (on Tomcat 7). I'am implementing a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to dynamically create my `DataSource`s. But the problem is that my `DataSource`'s information (name, url, etc..) is stored in a database itself.

```
@Component 
class DatasourceRegisteringBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor { 

  // This doesn't work
  @Autowired DatabaseService databaseService;

  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    // my code here ...
    // ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, i was trying to inject a service which can get me a list of all `DataSource`s from my database, but it doesn't work. Is the anyway to connect to the database and get that list within the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` class? Any other workaround will be welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s are a very special kind of concept in Spring. They are components that operate on `BeanDefinition` instances, which are a metamodel of the bean instances *to be created*.

That means, that at the point in time when the `BFPP`s are invoked, no bean instances have been created yet as the metamodel is about to be post processed (as the name suggests). Hence beans depended on by the `BFPP` will be initialized *extremely* early in the lifecycle of the container. Thus it's highly recommended to not depend on application components from `BFPP`s or - if really required - only on beans that don't necessarily trigger the creation of a lot of downstream components.

That said, you shouldn't depend on especially repositories from `BFPP`s as they usually require the creation of a lot of infrastructure components. I'd recommend getting the configuration properties that are required to connect to the configuration database (JDBC URL, username, password, etc.) and just create a throw-away `DataSource` that's only used to create a new `BeanDefinition` for a new `DataSource` that's going to be used by the application eventually.

So here are the recommended steps (from the top of my head - might need some tweaking):

- drop the autowiring of a `DataSource`
- configure an `@PropertySource` pointing to the properties containing the coordinates to connect
- inject the values of that `PropertySource` into the constructor of the `BFPP`:

  ```
  class YourBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    public YourBeanFactoryPostProcessor(@Value("#{properties.url}) String url, …) {
      // assign to fields
    }

    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {

      // 1. Create throw-away DataSource
      // 2. Create JdbcTemplate
      // 3. Use template to lookup configuration properties
      // 4. Create BeanDefinition for DataSource using properties just read
      // 5. Register BeanDefinition with the BeanFactory
    }
  }
  ```